# Colouring out of bounds as limits in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a raster so that values outside scale limits have the same colors of the scale limits themselves.

```
# Generate data
pp <- function (n,r=4) {
 x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n)
 df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
 df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
 df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6)
 df
}
pp200 <- pp(200)
ggplot(pp200, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
geom_raster() +
scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-0.5, 0.5))
```

Result:
[image: example image]

All out of bounds values are `grey50` (`na.value`)!

I have also tried with the `scale_fill_gradient2()` options:

```
oob=squish #This does not seem to exists anymore
```

and

```
oob=function(x, ...) x #does nothing
```

and

```
oob=clip #this does not work:
#Error in f(...) : argument "x2" is missing, with no default
```

How can I color the out of bound values, which are currently mapped to `NA`, with the limit values of the scale? In the above example, values `> 0.5` should be blue, `< -0.5` should be red. I know I can do that by cutting the dataset, using factors, but I want a continuous color scale. I can also use breaks to set the shown limits, but I want the full color scale to be displayed no matter of the plot contents. I would also like to avoid any modification of the data if possible.

Comment: @Axeman You mean as oob function or as modification to the data? Yes of course I can modify the data, but I'd like to avoid that. The reason is that, for example, if I want to use a `stat_summary()`, it gets screwed. Yes, I can work around that, but it seems a bit too hackish for a thing that should be simple (and which worked in previous ggplot versions using `oob=squish`)     (by the way this does not work `oob=function(z) ifelse(z < 0.5, ifelse(z > -0.5, z, -0.5), 0.5)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `oob = squish` doesn't seem to work anymore is that some of the functionality from `ggplot2` has been transferred to the `scales` package. Load `scales` first, or type `oob = scales::squish` instead.